# How to send a post request body as binary (equivalent to curl ... --data-binary) using the Node.js Request library?

Tags: node.js, curl, binary, http-post

I'm attempting to work with Google Cloud Vision but cannot seem to send the post body as binary as required.

Edit:
The following is now working:

```
request({
    url:"https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<api-key>",
    method:"post",
    headers:{
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(
          "requests":[{
              "image":{
                "content":<base64 encoded image data>
              },
              "features":[
                {
                  "type":"TEXT_DETECTION"
                }      
              ],
              "imageContext":{
                "languageHints": [
                  "ar"
                ]
                }        
            }]  
        )
},function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error);
    }else{
      console.log(body);
      res.send(body);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Apparently I forgot to add the post method in the request options. That was it, it's been resolved now.

Comment: You can close the question with your answer. It is a valid use case.

Comment: How do you get the `<base64 encoded image data>` with Node?